# Markdown Output: Style Code Blocks

Tags: javascript, php, syntax-highlighting, github-flavored-markdown

I'm using [Better Markdown Parser in PHP    http://parsedown.org/](http://parsedown.org/) to generate HTML for display from a markdown file. It uses GitHub Flavoured Markdown, including code blocks.

Code blocks are converted to something like this:

```
<pre>
    <code class="language-javascript">
        var message='hello';
        alert(message);
    </code>
</pre>
```

Does anybody know of a syntax highlighter, presumably in JavaScript, which highlights this format? I gather that GitHub does this on the server using ruby, which I’m happy to consider, but I would prefer JavaScript or PHP solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found one. The very excellent and easy-to use [Prism](http://prismjs.com/) does the job perfectly.